# netfilter's configuration to allow openvpn

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I've got a debian server at home, that I use to have a VPN access to my home computers.

I've redirected the openvpn port on the port 2000 : in my file "server.conf", I've added this :

```
#Server 
mode server 
proto udp 
port 2000
```

With the connexion tracking, I allow all the related and response connexions.

I've set up a rule, allowing everybody on the port 2000 :

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
```

however, it doesn't allow me to connect to my VPN (if I disable the firewall, I can connect without any problem).

So, what haven't I understood? does openvpn need another port?

Comment: compare: openvpn config: `proto udp` vs. iptables: `-p tcp`, I guess you need to sync these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your iptables rule: It should be for UDP, not for TCP. Additionally, your server gets the UDP traffic to port 2000 as your router rewrites the destination port and IP:

```
    iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p udp --dport 2000 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Sorry, i made an error while copy/pasting. I've edited my question.
Thank you for the UDP error, this was the problem.